# Modificar caracteres en una cadena

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente cadena

```
'POLYGON ((-58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993, -58.61272573499997 -34.552244351999946, -58.611851334999983 -34.552907077999976, -58.611473561999958 -34.552566878999983, -58.612331868999945 -34.55191298799997, -58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993))'
```

y necesito llegar a esta

```
[((-58.612406970999984 ,-34.55196600599993),(-58.61272573499997, -34.552244351999946),(-58.611851334999983, -34.552907077999976),(-58.611473561999958,-34.552566878999983),(-58.612331868999945,-34.55191298799997),(-58.612406970999984,-34.55196600599993))]
```

Disculpen si no logro poner un avance ya que no logre ninguno. No pretendo que se me de el resultado si no una orientacion para poder encaminar la solucion.

Comment: no se entiende lo que necesitas... porfavor edita tu pregunta y se especifico para que asi podamos ayudarte... saludos :)

Comment: @Mr.Manutri espero ahora se entienda mejor y disculpen

Comment: Convertir la cadena en una lista de tuplas es relativamente sencillo.. pero te consulto por las dudas: la cadena que estas mostrando es del tipo `WKT` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), para algo en particular necesitas convertirla en un lista de tuplas?  Estás usando alguna librería de GIS? esto último por que normalmente estas librerías tipo `shapely` ya saben como interpretar el formato `WKT`.

Comment: Es el resultado de un campo geometrico de sql que pasado a string **ToString()** me devuelve la primer lista

Comment: Seba convertir la cadena a la lista que quieres es relativamente sencillo en Python estándar usando [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) y similares o mediante expresiones regulares por ejemplo. Pero, coincido con la observación que hace Patricio, no se cual es la necesidad exacta de hacer lo que quieres y sería de ayuda algo más de contexto , más aún si trabajas con grandes cantidades de datos en cuyo caso el parseo puede conllevar una sobrecarga importante.

Comment: Efectivamente, la idea es que no estés cayendo en un problema del tipo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/31764, es decir ya tienes una solución en mente y sobre eso preguntas y no sobre el problema. No digo que este sea el caso, pero sabes que hay múltiples tipos de objetos dentro de la especificación WKT? Voy a responderte sobre como hacer lo que pides con el objeto `POLYGON`,  pero.. y si recibes un `POINT` o un `LINESTRING`, entonces la respuesta si bien válida para tu pregunta no te sirva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma bien sencilla es la siguiente:

```
cadena = 'POLYGON ((-58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993, -58.61272573499997 -34.552244351999946, -58.611851334999983 -34.552907077999976, -58.611473561999958 -34.552566878999983, -58.612331868999945 -34.55191298799997, -58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993))'

lista = [(float(e[0]),float(e[1])) for e in [e.split() for e in cadena[11:-2].split(",")]]
print(lista)

[(58.612406970999984, -34.55196600599993),
 (-58.61272573499997, -34.552244351999946),
 (-58.61185133499998, -34.552907077999976),
 (-58.61147356199996, -34.55256687899998),
 (-58.612331868999945, -34.55191298799997),
 (-58.612406970999984, -34.55196600599993)]
```

Usamos comprensión de listas de forma anidada:

- `cadena[11:-2].split(",")`, recortamos la cadena con un "slice" para quitar el texto y los paréntesis de apertura y cierre (solo queremos coordenadas y comas), luego hacemos un `split` por la coma, lo cual nos deja una lista con cada pareja de coordenadas.
- Luego de la lista anterior por cada elemento hacemos `e.split()` y ahora separamos las parejas de coordenadas por el espacio en una lista con dos elementos.
- Por último recorriendo nuevamente la lista `(float(e[0]),float(e[1]))` convertimos cada coordenada a un número de coma flotante y lo retornamos como tupla.

Atención: El resultado es una lista de tuplas, en tu ejemplo has indicado que requieres algo así como una lista con una sola tupla y con múltiples tuplas dentro, algo como esto `[((a,b),(b,c))]` en caso que no se trate de un error tipográfico y efectivamente requieras algo así, simplemente hay que hacer un ajuste mínimo :

```
lista = []
tupla = tuple((float(e[0]),float(e[1])) for e in [e.split() for e in cadena[11:-2].split(",")])
lista.append(tupla)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias en cuanto pueda pruebo las soluciones y les comento

Comment: Patricio disculpa mi poco conocimiento, me falto aclarar que no busco en la salida una tupla si no un cadena q se insertara en un campo del tipo string

Comment: Si necesitás una cadena, simplemente puedes convertir la lista así `str(lista)`

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya te han respondido cómo hacerlo usando python "a secas" (con sus funciones de cadenas), creo que tengo una respuesta que usa una biblioteca más adecuada a tu problema, que te permitirá convertir tipos de datos similares (basados en WKT) que puedan aparecerte en el futuro.

En tu historial de preguntas he visto que tienes varias relacionadas con datos geométricos y que en algunas de ellas usas la biblioteca python [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely). Pues bien, esta biblioteca tiene funciones para *parseado* de cadenas WKT, de las que tu caso es un ejemplo. Una vez las ha parseado, te ofrece montones de métodos para operar sobre ellas, tales como calcular su área, intersecciones con otras, verificar si contiene o no un punto, etc.

Por ejemplo, ejecutando lo siguiente en un notebook:

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
cadena = 'POLYGON ((-58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993, -58.61272573499997 -34.552244351999946, -58.611851334999983 -34.552907077999976, -58.611473561999958 -34.552566878999983, -58.612331868999945 -34.55191298799997, -58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993))'
g = loads(cadena)
```

Y en `g` tienes una variable de tipo `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon`, que entre otras cosas sabe dibujarse:

```
>>> g
```

[image: dibujo]

Obtener su área, o su centroide:

```
>>> print(g.area, g.centroid)
5.468957898656394e-07 POINT (-58.61209796852194 -34.5524066377988)
```

Y lo que buscabas, la lista de coordenadas de su contorno:

```
>>> list(g.boundary.coords)
[(-58.612406970999984, -34.55196600599993),
 (-58.61272573499997, -34.552244351999946),
 (-58.61185133499998, -34.552907077999976),
 (-58.61147356199996, -34.55256687899998),
 (-58.612331868999945, -34.55191298799997),
 (-58.612406970999984, -34.55196600599993)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion y ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres convertir tu dato puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
cadena = 'POLYGON ((-58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993, -58.61272573499997 -34.552244351999946, -58.611851334999983 -34.552907077999976, -58.611473561999958 -34.552566878999983, -58.612331868999945 -34.55191298799997, -58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993))'

cadena = var.replace('POLYGON ', '').replace('((', '').replace('))', '').split(', ')

result = tuple([tuple(x.split(' ')) for x in cadena])
```

Y si lo quieres en **float**

```
result = tuple([tuple([float(x) for x in x.split(' ')]) for x in cadena])
```

Aunque debes fijarte en los comentarios ya que puedes encontrar una solución mucho más fácil.